# Implementing google smart action with custom device trait

Tags: google-smart-home

I have been trying for a while now to create a kind of "controller" for my windows pc which is integrated with google assistant.
I would like to have actions like "Turn off the internet", "Shutdown" or "Open program".

However in trying to implement this with Google smart action API I see that it "only" supports a set of traits. I know I can "reuse" different traits for different actions, like "OnOff" to control pc power, but how about starting programs on my pc?

I would like to use natural commands (Hey Google, open Word), instead of the conversational API which is (Hey Google, talk to my pc -> open Word), but I would understand if that is not possible, since the traits are how Google HomeGraph knows which devices supports the users query.

Am I going into a rabbithole of impossibilities and should I just bite the bullet and use the Conversational API?

Any open source projects which is doing this would also be appreciated, end goal is implementing something myself, but inspiration is always nice.

Answer (score 0):

I previously [built my own PC integration](https://github.com/actions-on-google-labs/smart-pc-nodejs) with the smart home platform and gave it a few commands.

Going through smart home means that you cannot add custom device traits. Whichever exist in the platform are it. However, there are [quite a few traits](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits)  available for use.

In your set of use cases, there is an [AppSelector trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/appselector) and a [NetworkControl](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/networkcontrol) trait. You may be interested in using both of these.